Interpretation of the impact of n on the fourier transform of exp(np(w)) or way to simplify expression
My goal is to find
$$IFT\{exp(np(\omega)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp(np(\omega) + 2i\pi \omega f) d\omega $$
that is the Fourier transform of $exp(np(\omega))$
Here $n>0 \in {\rm I\!R}$
$p(\omega) = FT\{p(x)\}$
where p(x) is a distribution function of the form:
p(x) = $\frac{(\alpha - 1)}{x_m}(\frac{x}{x_m})^{-\alpha}$
$\alpha$ = 2.5,
$x_m$ = 0.1
This is a form of the Pareto distribution however that has no closed form fourier transform so I aim to find a way to rewrite this integral such that it is numerically stable so any simplification of the above integral in its full form would be very useful - that could be for example done by extracting the n via some property that I am potentially unaware of.

For the Fourier transform $$\mathcal{F}{\omega}\lefte^{n, p(\omega )}\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{n, p(\omega)}, e^{-2 i \pi f \omega} , d\omega\tag{1}$$ where $p(\omega)$ is the inverse Fourier transform $$p(\omega)=\mathcal{F}f^{-1}g(f)=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} g(f), e^{2 i \pi \omega f} , df\tag{2}$$ of the probability function $g(f)$, what is your definition of the probability function $g(f)$?

My probability function is the Pareto distribution. @StevenClark

There are several definitions at Pareto distribution-Definitions including
$$\bar{F}(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^{\alpha} & x\geq x_m \
1 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.\tag{1},$$
the CDF
$$F_X(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
1-\left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^{\alpha} & x\geq x_m \
0 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.\tag{2},$$
and the PDF
$$f_X(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\alpha x_m^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}} & x\geq x_m \
0 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}.$$

All three definitions involve the parameter $x_m$ as well as $\alpha$. Which of these three corresponds to your probability function associated with the inverse Fourier transform $p(\omega)$ and what is your assumed value of $x_m$?

In your last expression I believe $FT{p(x}$ should be $FT{p(x)}$ and for $$IFT{exp(n, p(\omega)-n)}=IFT{exp(n, FT{p(x)}-n)}$$ since $p(\omega)=IFT{f(x)}$ then $$f(x)=FT{p(\omega)}$$ and your last expression is equivalent to $$IFT{exp(n, p(\omega)-n)}=IFT{exp(n, f(\omega)-n)}?$$ Why would this equivalency hold, and what is your motivation for exploring the Fourier transform of an exponential function of an inverse Fourier transform?

I'm having problems making sense of this question.
Assuming $F_X(x)$ defined in formula (2) in my earlier comment note that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F_X(x)=1$ so the inverse Fourier transform $p(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x^{-1}F_X(x)$ doesn't converge in the usual sense, rather it involves a distributional term.

Assuming $p(\omega)=\mathcal{F}x^{-1}f_X(x)$ where $f_X(x)$ is defined in formula (3) in my earlier comment, I believe that $\lim\limits{\omega\to\pm\infty} p(\omega)=0$ so the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}\omega\exp(n, p(\omega))$ doesn't converge in the usual sense because $\lim\limits{\omega\to\pm\infty} \exp(n, p(\omega))=\exp(0)=1$.

I believe my updated post answers your questions @StevenClark however I am unclear of what you mean in you previous comment. So you think that the Fourier transform of the Pareto is infinite everywhere ?

I don't understand how
$$p(x)=(\alpha-1) \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha},\quad \alpha=2.5,, x_m=0.1$$
relates to a Pareto distribution which are piecewise functions as illustrated in the formulas in my earlier comment above.

Assuming the probability density function
$$f_X(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
(\alpha -1) \left(\frac{x}{\text{xm}}\right)^{-\alpha } & x\geq x_m \
0 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.$$
leads to the cumulative distribution function
$$f_x(x)=\int\limits_0^x f_X(y) , dy=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
x_m-x \left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^{\alpha } & x\ge x_m \
0 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.$$
and note that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f_x(x)=x_m=\frac{1}{10}$ which is inconsistent with a cumulative distribution function which should have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f_x(x)=1$.

But this problem is easily fixed by multiplying $f_X(x)$ and $f_x(x)$ by a scaling factor of $10$. Are you attempting to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform of the exponential of the Fourier transform
$$\mathcal{F}x\left\left{\begin{array}{cc}
(\alpha -1) \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha} & x\geq x_m \
0 & x<x_m \
\end{array}\right.
\right=\int\limits{x_m}^{\infty } (\alpha -1) \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}, e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} , dx?$$

Or are you attempting to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform  of the exponential of the Fourier transform
$$\mathcal{F}x\left (\alpha-1) \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} (\alpha-1) \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}, e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} , dx?$$

@StevenClark Yes you are correct about the scaling, sorry my formula should have an $x_m$ in the denominator. I will fix that. I am aiming to find the inverse fourier transform of the exponential of n times by the fourier transform.

Based on your comment below, my initial interpretation of your question in Case (1) below was not correct, so I added Case (2) below to address a second interpretation.

Case (1):

Assuming $\alpha=\frac{5}{2}$ and $x_m=\frac{1}{10}$, the Fourier transform of
$$p(x)=\frac{\alpha-1}{x_m} \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}\tag{1}$$
is
$$P(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x\left[p(x)\right](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha-1}{x_m} \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}\, e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} \, dx\\=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \omega \leq 0 \\
 \left(-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \pi ^2 \omega ^{3/2} & \omega>0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
where the Fourier transform integral in formula (2) above is treated as a Cauchy principal value.

Now consider the inverse Fourier Transform
$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}\left[e^{n\, P(\omega)}\right](x)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}\left[(1-\theta(\omega))\, e^{n\, 0}\right](x)+\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}\left[\theta(\omega)\, e^{n\, \left(-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \pi^2 \omega^{3/2}}\right](x)\\=\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 1\, e^{2 i \pi \omega x} \, d\omega+\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{n\, \left(-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \pi^2 \omega^{3/2}}\, e^{2 i \pi \omega x} \, d\omega\\=\frac{\delta (x)}{2}-\frac{i}{2 \pi x}+\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{n\, \left(-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \pi^2 \omega^{3/2}}\, e^{2 i \pi \omega x} \, d\omega\tag{3}.$$

I'm not sure there's a closed form for the final integral in formula (3) above, but I believe formula (3) above can be evaluated via numeric integration as illustrated in Figures (1) to (3) below. The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ in formula (3) above is zero for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except at $x=0$ where its undefined, and consequently $f(x)$ is also undefined at $x=0$.


Figure (1): Illustration of $|f(x)|$ for $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange


Figure (2): Illustration of $\Re(f(x))$ for $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange


Figure (3): Illustration of $\Im(f(x))$ for $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange

Case (2):

Assuming
$$p(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\alpha-1}{x_m} \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha} & x\geq x_m \\  0 & x<x_m \\ \end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$
for $\alpha=\frac{5}{2}$ and $x_m=\frac{1}{10}$ one has
$$P(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x\left[p(x)\right](\omega)=\int\limits_{x_m}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha-1}{x_m} \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^{-\alpha}\, e^{-2 i \pi \omega x} \, dx=\frac{1}{25} \left(\pi^2 \sqrt{10} \left(i \omega \sqrt{|\omega|}-|\omega|^{3/2}+2 \omega^{3/2} \left(C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \sqrt{\omega}\right)-i\, S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \sqrt{\omega}\right)\right)\right)+5 e^{-\frac{1}{5} i \pi \omega} (5-2 i \pi \omega)\right)\tag{5}$$
where $C$ and $S$ are the Fresnel integrals.

For $P(\omega)$ defined in formula (5) above evaluating the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{n\, P(\omega)}$ is problematic because $\lim\limits_{\omega\to\pm\infty} P(\omega)=0$ and consequently $\lim\limits_{\omega\to\pm\infty} e^{n\, P(\omega)}=e^0=1$, but since
$$\mathcal{F}_x^{-1}[1](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1\, e^{2 i \pi x \omega} \, d\omega=\delta(x)\tag{6}$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function one has
$$g(x)=\mathcal{F}_x^{-1}[e^{n\, P(\omega)}](\omega)=\delta(x)+\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right)\, e^{2 i \pi x \omega} \, d\omega\tag{7}$$

I'm not sure there's a closed form for the integral in formula (7) above, and I believe evaluating formula (7) above via numeric integration as $n$ increases is problematic because as $n$ increases the decay rate decreases and the high-frequency components increase as illustrated in Figures (4) to (6) below.

Figures (4) to (6) below illustrate $\left|e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right|$, $\Re\left(e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right)$, and $\Im\left(e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right)$ evaluated at $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange respectively where $P(\omega)$ is defined in formula (5) above.


Figure (4): Illustration of $\left|e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right|$ evaluated at $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange


Figure (5): Illustration of $\Re\left(e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right)$ evaluated at $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange


Figure (6): Illustration of $\Im\left(e^{n\, P(\omega)}-1\right)$ evaluated at $n=1$ and $n=10$ in blue and orange

I have never heard of Cauchy principal values and this is something that I will look into, I need to however set the lower limit of the integral to $x_m$ apologies if this wasn't clear earlier. How would this change things. Is there any material which you can suggest I read.

It is unclear how you get the result in eqn2 also.

See MathWorld and Wikipedia for an introduction to Cauchy principal value. I evaluated the integral in formula (2) using Mathematica. Setting the lower limit to $x_m$ changes things considerably, but I also investigated this case and will add it to my answer when I have time.

Is there any way you would be able to share this code file with me? I have tried coding this in Mathematica however due to a lack of experience I am unable to get this working and Mathematica is unable to run the integral in the way I code it.

@JohnSmith You can evaluate the Fourier transform in formula (5) as
Block[{a=5/2,xm=1/10},FullSimplify[FourierTransform[(a-1)/xm (x/xm)^(-a) HeavisideTheta[x-xm],x,w,GenerateConditions->True,FourierParameters->{0,-2 Pi}]]]

where I substituted $a$ for $\alpha$, $xm$ for $x_m$, and $w$ for $\omega$.

Is there any way you would be able to publish this notebook? I completely understand if you would not like to. I only ask as running code to plot the output of this function causes an abort error. (since it takes too long to run on the student plan)

@JohnSmith I don't believe there's any way to share a file on Math StackExchange, but I included plots of $e^{n, P(\omega)}$ exported from my notebook in my answer above. I can add plots of $P(\omega)$ to my answer above if that's what you're interested in, but I suspect you're doing something wrong because it only takes a few seconds to generate plots $P(\omega)$ and $e^{n, P(\omega)}$ on a Raspberry Pi 5. One way to reduce the execution time is to limit the number of points plotted by adding "PlotPoints->100,MaxRecursion->0" to the plot command for example.

@JohnSmith Reducing plot points works better when a function only has low frequency components, but it tends to distort the function when it has higher frequency components. You can also plot $P(\omega)$ on WolframAlpha.
